# Using an application's notification to invoke another application/activity

Tags: android, notifications

How can I use an application's notification to start a new application. The NotificationManager does not provide me with a method that lets me access the generated notifications. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create notification with `PendingIntent`. From [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html):

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

private static final int HELLO_ID = 1;
mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
```

Where `MyClass` is activity you want to start from notification.